# Is there any way to determine if a Terraform resource is being created within module

Tags: terraform

I am trying to output a property of a resource but only if the resource is being created now.

Is there any way to determine within a module whether a resource is now going to be created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to accomplish this at least in the situation where a resource is now being created for the first time.

This will only work if the resource you are trying to track has a matching `data` resource.

The idea is to use the `data` resource to check if this resource already exists and then if it does not exist set the output variable to `null`.

For example with `cloudflare_zone` resource there is a corresponding `cloudflare_zones` data source:

```
resource "cloudflare_zone" "cloudflare_zone" {
    zone = "zone_name"
}

// Check if zone already exists to determine whether to output the zone's nameservers
data "cloudflare_zones" "exists" {
    filter {
        name = "zone_name"
    }
}

output "cloudflare_zone_nameservers" {
    value = length(data.cloudflare_zones.exists.zones) == 0 ? cloudflare_zone.cloudflare_zone.name_servers : null
}
```

FYI this will only work if the resources corresponding data source does not throw an error when the resource does not exist.